# Opaque text with transparent background in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

In wxpython, you can change the transparency of a frame using 'SetTransparent()' function.

There is a sample app that shows the use of transparent frames [here](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Transparent%20Frames). However, the text also fades as the transparency changes (predictably). Is it possible to make it so the text always remains opaque while the background changes transparency?

Comment: you could try `Layered windows` described here (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34158/Cool-Semi-transparent-and-Shaped-Dialogs-with-Stan). This is C/C++ code but with `win32api` module probably it's possible to port it to python...